# Add the "SAMBA File Server" role to a server running SCO Unix?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, unix, network-share

We're trying to get network access to a hard drive on a server running SCO Unix from Windows Servers. I beleive we need to add the role "SAMBA File Server" to the server so we can mount the drive as a network share that we can access from Windows.

Is it possible to add the SAMBA role to a SCO Unix operating system? Are there any gotchas or concerns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, samba is compatible with SCO Unix. You can check the information at http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/samba_help/index.html

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated...

Comment: Is there a walkthrough for installing it? Or can I use the same procedure to install on a linux box?

Comment: On a linux box just install the `samba` package and then adjust the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to your needs.